# Pass scroll gestures through container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have a smaller element on a screen that I'm using a PageView to build, since I need that snap-to effect for each item in the list. But this means the edges will be flush, with no visual indication that the PageView element is scrollable. I tried putting the PageView in a stack with a container on top (like an overlay) that had a linear gradient to "shadow" the sides to make the element look rounded, but this blocks the scrolling gesture from reaching the PageView.

My question is this: is there a widget that I'm not finding that allows scroll gestures to pass through it, while visually appearing on top of other elements? I know I can draw smaller-than-the-PageView elements on top of it, but I'm just wondering if someone else has done something like this successfully.

EDIT: here is a simplified version of the working code. I can't swipe to the next page view.

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(35.0),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              PageView(
                children: [
                  Container(color: Colors.blue[200]),
                  Container(color: Colors.red[200]),
                  Container(color: Colors.deepPurple[200])
                ]
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                    colors: [ Color.fromARGB(50, 0, 0, 0), Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0), Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0), Color.fromARGB(50, 0, 0, 0) ],
                    stops: [ 0.05, 0.25, 0.75, 0.95 ]
                  )
                )
              )
            ]
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: this shouldn't be happening as long as there is no input expecting widget over the pageview you should be good to go if there is then you should check its `hittestbehavior` property, please post the working code

Comment: @Yadu there aren't any other gesture detectors in the tree for this element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Containers block scroll input, so I decided to go another route with something like Pedro R.'s suggestion. I created a page indicator at the bottom of the PageView that indicates which page the user is currently on and how many pages total there are. Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/CodeSquatch/pen/ZEWKawM) I made to showcase the effect.

**EDIT AND BEST ANSWER**: So I found exactly what I was looking for a little while later. It's a class called `IgnorePointer`, and it works like the below code example. This will allow you to swipe on the `PageView`. Try removing the `IgnorePointer` and your swiping becomes blocked.

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    PageView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(color: Colors.deepPurple[300]),
        Container(color: Colors.blue[300]
      ]
    ),
    IgnorePointer(
      child: Container(
        color: Color.fromARGB(100, 100, 100, 100)
      )
    )
  ]
)
```

And the code to go with the code pen

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyWidget({Key key}): super(key: key);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(35.0),
          child: PageIndicator()
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  PageIndicator({Key key}): super(key: key);
  
  @override
  _PageIndicatorState createState() => _PageIndicatorState();
}

class _PageIndicatorState extends State<PageIndicator> {
  int _pageNum;
  PageController _controller;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageNum = 0;
    _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        PageView(
          controller: _controller,
          onPageChanged: (page) {
            setState(() {
              _pageNum = page;
            });
          },
          children: [
            Container(color: Colors.blue[200]),
            Container(color: Colors.red[200]),
            Container(color: Colors.deepPurple[200])
          ]
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 80,
            child: Center(
              child: Text("${_pageNum + 1} / 3", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0))
            )
          )
        )
      ]
    );
  }// end build
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PageIndicatorWidget. Something like this:
var pageController = PageController();

```
          Stack(
            children: [
              PageView(
                controller: pageController,
                children: [
                  Container(color: Colors.blue[200]),
                  Container(color: Colors.red[200]),
                  Container(color: Colors.deepPurple[200])
                ]
              ),
          PageIndicator(
              layout: PageIndicatorLayout.WARM,
              size: 10.0,
              controller: pageController,
              space: 5.0,
              count: 3,
              color: Colors.green,
              activeColor: Colors.gray,
            ),
              
            ]
          )
```